# Remove duplicates from col1 when condition in col2 is met

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2(SP2) 10.50.4263

I have application number in col1 and an indicator (0 or 1) for first time buyers(ftb) in col2.  Each application can have 1 or 2 applicants.  For applications with two applicants, I get two entries for application as so:

```
application  ftb
-----------  ---
1234          0
12345         0
12345         1
2345          1
23456         0
23456         0
```

The desired result is each unique application and ftb.  If an application has multiple ftb values...take the highest (its always a 0 or 1).

I would like to see this:

```
application  ftb
-----------  ---
1234          0
12345         1
2345          1
23456         0
```

I've been trying to use PARTITION but...not any luck.  The table is provided to me and I'm unable to alter it.  This needs to be done in sql and not excel.  I've tried a million permutations and even self joins to solve this.  Stuck.

Can some kind soul point the way?

Comment: Does it also have an ID column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
application,
MAX(ftb) AS ftb
FROM
yourTable
GROUP BY application
```

I understood your question like you want to have only the rows presented in your desired output in the table and delete the others, right? The simplest way to achieve this, is to use a temporary table.

```
SELECT
application,
MAX(ftb) AS ftb
INTO #yourTempTable
FROM
yourTable
GROUP BY application;
```

Then delete all other rows either by

```
DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE application IN (SELECT DISTINCT application FROM #yourTempTable)
```

And finally insert from the temporary table back into your table again.

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (application, ftb) 
SELECT application, ftb FROM #yourTempTable;
```

And that's it.

Comment: OP is looking for a cleanup (`delete`) statement.

Comment: @juergen d Where does OP state that?  In fact he states that he cannot change the source table...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a max aggregate on ftb combined with a group by on the application column:

```
Select application, Max(ftb) from yourtable group by application;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you also have an ID column:

-- delete all the zeroes that also have a 1

```
DELETE FROM yourTable
WHERE ftb = 0 
AND application IN
(SELECT s.application
FROM yourTable AS s
WHERE s.ftb = 1)
```

-- only keep the most resent per application

```
DELETE FROM yourTable
WHERE ID NOT IN 
(SELECT MAX(s.ID)
FROM yourTable AS s
GROUP BY s.application)
```

Answer (score 0):

To return the sequence number of a row within a partition of column "application", use the ranking function [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) with the ORDER BY clause on column "ftb". So you can delete all the duplicate rows

```
 ;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY application ORDER BY ftb DESC) AS rn
  FROM dbo.YourTable
  )
  DELETE cte
  WHERE rn > 1
```

See demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bafb7/1)